# Hidden layers neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, networks

So I am designing a neural network which will decide which way a character should move and look. 
I was thinking of breaking it into two different networks one for movement and one for direction. 
So for movement the network will be given 5 booleans and 4 ints. Representing: is it allowed to move, can it move forward, back, left and right, current x and y along with target point x and y. It will then output 2 results which signify the movement in either the x and y direction.
For direction facing, I will enter x and y coordinates for the player, the x and y coordinates for a target and if the target is visible. If target is visible its output will be an angle from the current player to the target.

I am using dlib, with cuDNN and a gtx1070. 
So my question is, what sized network will I be needing and is it possible to calculate it given the library and my hardware. I am more then happy to run the processing for more then a week.

Thanks alot!

```
output_type expected_output(sample_type sample)
    {
        output_type to_return;
        if(sample(ALLOWED_TO_MOVE) > 0)
        {
            to_return(MOVEMENTY) = 0;
            to_return(MOVEMENTX) = 0;
            return to_return;
        }
        if (sample(CAN_MOVE_Left) && !sample(CAN_MOVE_RIGHT))
        {
            to_return(MOVEMENTX) = LEFT;
        }
        else if(sample(CAN_MOVE_RIGHT) && !sample(CAN_MOVE_Left))
        {
            to_return(MOVEMENTX) = RIGHT;
        }
        else if (!sample(CAN_MOVE_RIGHT) && !sample(CAN_MOVE_Left))
        {
            to_return(MOVEMENTX) = NONE;
        }
        else
        {
            if(sample(PLAYERX) > sample(TARGETX))
                to_return(MOVEMENTX) = LEFT;
            else
                to_return(MOVEMENTX) = RIGHT;
        }

        if (sample(CAN_MOVE_FORWARD) && !sample(CAN_MOVE_BACK))
        {
            to_return(MOVEMENTY) = UP;
        }
        else if (sample(CAN_MOVE_BACK) && !sample(CAN_MOVE_FORWARD))
        {
            to_return(MOVEMENTY) = BACK;
        }
        else if (!sample(CAN_MOVE_BACK) && !sample(CAN_MOVE_FORWARD))
        {
            to_return(MOVEMENTY) = NONE;
        }
        else
        {
            if (sample(PLAYERY) > sample(TARGETY))
                to_return(MOVEMENTY) = UP;
            else
                to_return(MOVEMENTY) = BACK;
        }

        return to_return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have what looks like 5 input units for each network and what looks like one or two outputs, this is probably something which can be done with at most one hidden layer with 10 units or less. Anything much larger would just be encouraging overfitting.

Since such a network will be extremely small, I expect it would take somewhere from a few seconds to a few minutes to train even on a CPU, nevermind a GPU.

Comment: thanks for the reply but after an hour of running with 9 inputs and 20 nodes in 1 hidden layer has resulted in an average error of 0.2 1/2(o-r)^2  which means that the difference between expected vs output is 0.45 and where the output is between 0 and 1. This doesn't seem very accurate what so ever.

Will try with 30 in one layer and 10 in another.

Comment: Is this error on the train or validation set? How much data is there?

Comment: There is infinite data, I am just generating it (looping through all possible combinations) continuously where the entity can be on a 600x600 field.
For train I am just setting the data then letting dlib go from there using: http://dlib.net/mlp_ex.cpp.html as a base. With the validation set being created with the code I posted above. @shimao

Comment: If you are looping, be careful that your data is shuffled properly.

Comment: Thanks very much! So rather then doing this: https://hastebin.com/uxuyasufod.lisp
I should be doing this: https://hastebin.com/ujizunumep.pl except replace rand() with something not so bad.

thanks! again
@shimao